# Extract users from specific OU or CN using DSInternals.Replication

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am using DSInternals.Replication Nuget package in order to get accounts from AD remotely using these lines in code:

NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(logInf, password);
string serverName = "DC01";
DirectoryReplicationClient directoryReplication = new DirectoryReplicationClient(serverName, RpcProtocol.TCP, credential);
accountsList = directoryReplication.GetAccounts(distinguishedNameDomain);

If I pass "CN=CSdepartment,DC=test,DC=local" as a distinguishedNameDomain to GetAccounts(), the error pops up due to the unknown context. However, if I pass "DC=test,DC=local", everything works correctly. Now I am wondering whether it is possible to pass a distinguished name of a certain OU or CN to the function GetAccounts() in order to filter out the scope of searching for accounts in a database (e.g. if my AD database contains 10000+ users, the performance decreases accordingly because I get all users from main domain object).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in an Active Directory environment with 100k+ user objects, you don't always want data for all of them returned. From my tests I don't think its possible to pass the DN of an OU to the GetAccounts() method, it has to be the DN of the domain itself. I ended up using Linq to filter based on the DN of the OU of the users I was interested in. It might not be the most efficient way of doing it, but it does work:

```
var domainPath = "DC=your,DC=domain,DC=com";
var targetOU = "OU=Sales,DC=your,DC=domain,DC=com";
using (DirectoryReplicationClient cl = new DirectoryReplicationClient("DC1.your.domain.com", RpcProtocol.TCP, new NetworkCredential("username", "password"))
{
    var salesAccounts = cl.GetAccounts(domainPath).Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.DistinguishedName, targetOU, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
    // do something with the objects in salesAccounts
}
```

Hope this helps.